# iterar en objeto javascript agrupado

Tags: javascript, array, angular

Estoy creando una funcion que me agrupada datos recibidos para luego convertirlos en PDF. la cuestion es que debo hacer que una parte del codigo sea recursivo para iterar en los diferentes niveles de agrupacion:

una muestra de la data sin agrupar que obtengo es esta:

```
    [
      {    
          "categoria": "categoria generica1",
          "tipo": "inventario general1",
          "producto": "fghjfghjfghj",
          "marca": "marca generica1",
          "precio": 500,
          "propiedad": "propiedad generica1",
      },
      {
         
          "categoria": "categoria generica1",
          "tipo": "inventario general1",
          "producto": "testfgfgfgfg",
          "marca": "marca generica3",
          "precio": 500,
          "propiedad": "propiedad generica3",
      },
      {
         
          "categoria": "categoria generica1",
          "tipo": "inventario general2",
          "producto": "testfgfgfgfg",
          "marca": "marca generica4",
          "precio": 500,
          "propiedad": "propiedad generica2",
      }
    ]
```

con esta funcion agrupo mis datos usando la libreria **lodash** de esta manera, cabe resaltar que la cantidad de filas por la que esta funcion agrupa es dinamica:

```
    var nest = (seq: any, keys: string | any[]) => {
        if (!keys.length) return seq;
        var first = keys[0];
        var rest = keys.slice(1);
        return mapValues(groupBy(seq, first), function (value: any) {           
          return nest(value, rest)
        });
      };

esta es una muestra de como visualmente la data es agrupada:

{
  "marca generica1": {
      "categoria generica1": {
          "propiedad generica1": [
              {
                  "categoria": "categoria generica1",
                  "tipo": "inventario general1",
                  "producto": "fghjfghjfghj",
                  "marca": "marca generica1",
                  "precio": 500,                  
                  "propiedad": "propiedad generica1",
              }
          ]
      },
  }
}
```

ahora que la data esta agrupada necesito iterar a todos los niveles de agrupacion para luego pasarselo a la libreria JSPDF e imprimir un reporte agrupado de esta manera por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

intento hacer recursiva esta funcion pero no obtengo el resultado deseado:

```
  const ungroup = (data) => {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
      let value = data[key];          
      if (typeof(value) === 'string') console.log(value);          
      
      if (typeof(value) === 'object') {
        Object.keys(value).forEach(function(key2) {        
          console.log(value[key2]);
        });
      }
      ungroup(value)
    });
  }
```

ungroup(temp);

GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO.

Comment: Por que no simplemente haces una columna de la categoría, marca y propiedad y te saltas la agrupación de datos. De la manera que lo estas haciendo será más difícil filtrar después en excel.

Comment: Necesito agrupar porque debo mostrar un total por cada uno de los niveles de agrupacion

Comment: Pero podes hacer la suma con un Reduce sobre los que cumplan con la agrupación que queres, sin necesidad de reestructurar los datos, haces unico de cada categoria y luego recorres ese unico, y asi para cada uno.